# Card with horizontal scrollable content

Tags: material-design, guidelines, android, google-materials-design, material

I wonder if placing horizontal content inside a Card (like an image list in the Reply material spp) is breaking material design guidance? [image: Reply material app]

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the "Contained collections" section of the Material Design component guidelines for "Cards" to find your answer:

https://material.io/components/cards/#card-collections

"Card collections can be placed within a container, and be scrolled within it." (the example is horizontally scrollable).

Comment: Let me disagree. According to "Contained collections" section: The container for a collection should not be a card. Also, an image in the horizontal list is not a card. This is just an image

Comment: My answer was to the question of whether Material Design supports horizontal content within cards. As you've read, it does. In other words, placing horizontal content within a card is acceptable. 

There are actually two questions being asked here. First, is horizontal content within cards supported in the Material Design guidelines (which is what I answered). The other question is if this particular app has adhered to the guidelines (which is the question you've answered).